# Infragistics UltraGrid rows displayed from bottom to top

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I need to display rows in UltraGrid starting from bottom and going towards the top rather then normally where they are displayed from the top to the bottom.
Is there a setting of a property that needs to be set to achieve this display? I can't seem to find it.

Example of required layout

[image: Grid]

Comment: Applying a sortorder to the datasource?

Comment: The sort order doesn't make any different, it just changes the order of the rows. I need to change position of the rows within the grid - please see the added picture of the grid layout.

Comment: So, if you have just 3 rows, the filling of the grid start from the bottom and proced upwards and stop after the third row leaving  empty space till the top of the grid?

Comment: Three rows is only an example of display. I could have from 1 row to any number of rows. I'm not sure what do you mean by saying - the filling of the grid?

Comment: If you have only one row, you want this row to be displayed at the bottom of the grid and empty space above that row till the top of the grid?

Comment: I have never seen this kind of functionality in UltraGrid. Perhaps I am wrong, but I suppose that it is not possible. If someone of Infragistics looks at this question we could have a definitive answer

Comment: Infragistics team just confirmed that this functionality is not available in UltraGrid. Thank you for your help Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality isn't built into the WinGrid control and you should log a new product idea on the [NetAdvantage for Windows Forms product idea page](http://ideas.infragistics.com/forums/192359-windows-forms) for this if you are looking for this functionality.

You may be able to do something like this using a creation filter to move the existing rows if there are not enough rows to fill the grid.  If you do pursue this you would still need to sort the rows so that they are already in the correct order first and they you would move the existing rows down when they don't fill the entire grid.  There are more details on creation filters in the [help](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Win_Creation_Filter.html).